# Error message in calculator code

Tags: c#, winforms

I am coding for calculator in c#.net. I am having an error message on txtDisplay in txtDisplay.Text. the error says "The name 'txtDisplay' does not exists in the current context".My code so far is:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Calc    
{      
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    public Form1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnOne_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text + btnOne.Text;
    }
```

Comment: You'd need to show also the other part of the `partial` class.

Comment: I assume txtDisplay is meant to be a TextBox on your form. Have you actually added it in designer mode?

Answer (score 0):

I tested the following code and it works fine.  Like the comments have said you will get this error if you have not yet created an element with the name txtDisplay.  More code would be helpful so I can edit my answer accordingly.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnOne_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtDisplay.Text += btnOne.Text;
    }
}
```